# Get path two directories above the path to current class file

Tags: java

I want to get the path uptil two directories above the path to the current class file.I am using this:

```
 Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

but it only gives path to current class file whereas I want to get path uptil parent of parent of this.
Is there any clean way of getting this without using substring?

Comment: You could add `../` that will tell OS to go up one level from current directory: `pathToCurrentDirectory + "../../"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a `File` from the URL you can call `getParentFile()` on it:

```
URL fileUrl = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
File file = new File(fileUrl.toURI);
String grandParent = file.getParentFile().getParent();
```

This should also work:

```
String grandParent = Test.class.getResource("../../").toString();
```